# Firebase: how to tell if field is unique?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a firestore query that tells me if a value is unique (e.g. username)

```
isUnique(value) {
  return db.collection('users')
  .where('username', '==', value)
  .get({source: 'cache'})
  .then((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot, snapshot.size, snapshot.docs)

    return snapshot.size === 0
  })
```

But this doesn't seem to work? thoughts?

part of this problem may stem from vuelidate, whereby `isUnique` is a validation function on a text field.

```js
    async isUnique(value) {
        /** previousVuelidateUsernameCall and 
        * previousVuelidateUsernameValue are added to 
        * prevent too many calls. If cache is added to the `get()`
        * the first call occurs too soon and the cache is never updated.
        */
        if (this.previousVuelidateUsernameCall === value) {
          return this.previousVuelidateUsernameValue
        }

        let results = await db.collection('users')
        .where('username', '==', value)
        .get() //{source: 'cache'}
        .then((snapshot) => {
          return snapshot.size === 0
        })

        this.previousVuelidateUsernameValue = results
        this.previousVuelidateUsernameCall = value
        return results
      }

    },
```

Comment: Your code looks ok and should work. Of course, when calling `isUnique()` you have to wait for the returned promise to resolve.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I’ve tried a sync await and it wasn’t doing it

Comment: Using `then` should work  `isUnique('xyz').then(r => {
        console.log(r);
      });`

Comment: @SumNeuron As Renaud says, this code looks fine. If you have a problem when calling it, show the minimal code that reproduces *that* problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen part of the probelm is that I am using it with vuelidate and it gets called too repeatedly. If I add the cache options, then the first call happens before firebase is ready so the cached result is incorrect. I solve it by adding a variable `prevResults` and `prevValue` and only calling when `prevValue` is different from current value

Comment: Don't describe your code in words in a comment please. Instead add the actual code that reproduces the problem to the question itself. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more hints on how to do that, which drastically increases the chances someone can help you.